# Underscorejs and gettext name conflict

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, gettext

How do you mix underscorejs and gettext for _("")?

What do you think is better to give gettext another function name or rename underscorejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Underscore's `noConflict`](http://underscorejs.org/#noConflict) method, for example:

```
// gettext is already loaded here,
// so _ variable points to Gettext instance

var underscore = _.noConflict();
```

Now you can access Underscore's methods from `underscore` variable and gettext's from `_`.

**UPD:** Excuse me, misunderstood. Personally, I think the one should reserve `_` for Underscore and use `gt` for Gettext. The reason behind it is that using Underscore and seeing it as `_` seems to be more common for JS developers.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna reserve `_` for `underscore` since its considered a better practice in JS world.